# Retrieving Android Data and passing it to to PHP WHERE Clause

Tags: java, php, android

As the title says. What code should I include in my java code that i can retrieve and pass it to my PHP.

Here is my PHP Code

```
<?PHP
include_once("connection.php");

if(isset($_POST['TableNum'])){ $TableNum = $_POST['TableNum']; } 
$TableNum = null;
$sql = "SELECT Name, Price, orderlist.Quantity FROM menu INNER JOIN orderlist ON orderlist.MenuID=menu.MenuID WHERE orderlist.TableNum='+$TableNum+' "; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$json = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $json['menu'][]=$row;
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
echo json_encode($json);
```

Here is my Java Code

I need this variable to be passed in my php script as my where clause.

```
final TextView idtable = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblTableNum);

    final TextView idtable = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblTableNum);
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Orderlist.this);
    String aa = getResources().getString(R.string.Table_Num);
    String tableID = sp.getString(getString(R.string.Table_Num), aa);
    idtable.setText(tableID);

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);      
    String url = "http://192.168.123.1/1purple/readOrder.php";
    try {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject table = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        JSONArray data = table.getJSONArray("menu");
        //JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(url));
        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map;
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("Name", c.getString("Name"));
            map.put("Quantity", c.getString("Quantity"));
            map.put("Price", c.getString("Price"));
            MyArrList.add(map);
        }
        SimpleAdapter sAdap;
        sAdap = new SimpleAdapter(Orderlist.this, MyArrList, R.layout.orderlist_arrangement,
                new String[] {"Name", "Quantity", "Price"}, new int[] {R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3});      
        lv.setAdapter(sAdap);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("Log", "Failed" +e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }           
 }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ? You want to pass an argument from your application to your server when calling your readOrder.php file ?

Comment: @galath yes, i wanted it to be dynamic therefor i want to pass the said variable to php file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem AS THIS one of yours i have chosen to use volley library on android part where it helped me to pass input variable to php where clause
 refer to this post and check the answer:

[How to parse multiple rows with jsonOject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45330098/how-to-parse-multiple-rows-with-jsonoject/45330447?noredirect=1#comment77641602_45330447)

or follow the followithing tutorial watch function called  **function StoreUserInfo** and refer to second part to activity called **RegisterActivity.java** these can help you to fetch using where clause:

https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/androidwithphp/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql/